# Bootstrap / Css - 2 DIV same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got HTML+CSS code. I need 1st div (row-1, white colored) to take first half of the container height, and 2nd div (row-2, orange-colored) to take the second part.
Here is my html:
http://pastebin.com/ipiEKHBZ
and my css:
http://pastebin.com/jtxw695F
[image: screen]

Comment: Try giving `col-*-6` for all the `medias` to your 2 `rows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised answer: After realising the default approach did not work with your HTML, this should work. You have classes .content-row-1 and 2 respectively. You can use those to tell the corresponding rows to always use a certain portion of the height. For this to work you also need to manually fix the positioning. (Someone correct me if this can be done more elegantly) For example those classes could look something like:

```
    .content-row-1 {
       background: #eee;
       position: absolute;
       top: 10%;
       display: block;
       height: 40%;  
       width: 100%;
    }
```

I noticed that your footer already takes 10% of the height and and assumed you did not want any overlap or gaps. For that to work you should also give your header a percentage for height (10% in my example to keep things simple).

And for the future: try using https://jsfiddle.net/ when showing your code samples. I put it together at https://jsfiddle.net/kvbyk3f1/.

Comment: Well, thanks. That solved my problem with two divs. 
I wanted to ask an additions question - what's the best way to use columns of bootstrap here to change body elements whenever screen changes? 
I mean now it's 4x2 layout only cause I whenever I put something like col-xs-12 for an any of these elements. So they are going to be 4x2 row in md, 1x8 rows in xs etc. Images are going crazy then

Comment: You should take another careful look at the pre-defined classes for different screen sizes at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: I did. It's about how to displat an element properly inside a col-XX class

Comment: Basically, you will have to specify behavior for all variants by adding the -xs- AND -md- classes, you are currently only using -xs-. Your question seems to be a bit more complex, so maybe just start a new one instead of solving this in the comments.